# What 's path of dropbox when I want to get all files(and folders) from dropbox.com/home

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

On drobbox api, I see a get_metadata. It require :
+ accessToken
+ request -> path

using rest API
https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/get_metadata

What's path of dropbox? I want to get all files and folders that such dropbox.com/home.

Answer (score 2):

The root of the Dropbox account should be specified as the empty string: "". However the [/files/get_metadata](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-get_metadata) endpoint doesn't support querying on the root, since there isn't any metadata to return for it anyway.

Instead, to list the root of a Dropbox account using Dropbox API v2, you would use the [/files/list_folder](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder) and [/files/list_folder/continue](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder-continue) endpoints. For example, calling /files/list_folder with curl would look like this:

```
curl -X POST https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder \
 --header "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE" \
 --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
 --data "{\"path\": \"\"}"
```

Comment: https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder?access_token=... I did not get data from this link